# Where is code I get in MS ACCESS in MDB or MDE file extension

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I m newly to the MS access, I didn’t getting where is the code see and edit. So I can login to my application.
When try open the my application in .MDE in MSAccess I am getting authorisation error-> your login is unauthorised please try again later.
Please answer me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open the MDB file.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the *VBE*, the VBA code editor.

That's where your code is.

Answer (score 0):

An MDE file is an old compiled version of an MDB database.  As such you cannot normally get at the code, so if you don't have the original MDB file you are in trouble! [These people](http://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion.asp) provide a commercial service to restore a MDB from a MDE.  I have never needed to use them, so cannot comment on how reliable the result is.

Comment: I have original MDB File I don’t know where is code in MDB or MDE application from 2009 ,So I need know where is code is and how to debug the code. Means in MDB OR MDE file?

Comment: Code will be in MDB file

Comment: Thank you, just for my understanding purpose just reply me back (In MDB file->database tool ->Visual Basic-> then I get list code file correct?.)

Comment: or each form can have its own code also. So, you can open a form in design mode, and there will  be code behind for forms, and even some reports can/might have code. In many cases you need to hold down the shift key during startup since startup code often runs to hide  most of the access UI and thus you can't get into design mode without a lot of effort. So hold down shift key during startup  to prevent  the startup code from running. Once done, you should be able to see all objects  in the nave pane (make sure to select all objects).